# Why doesn't this tag wiki appear even though it shows in the edit history?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

The [terminfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminfo) tag appears to have no tag wiki:

> [image: There is no tag wiki for this tag ... yet!]

The weird thing is, if you click ["history"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30003082/revisions), it shows that there was in fact an approved edit.

If you click "edit tag wiki", it shows the tag wiki source there.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/31089) and got the missing content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really a bug, it is simply what happens when a tag has a wiki, but no excerpt.

It is possible for example that the author of the wiki suggested both the main part and the excerpt, but only the main body was accepted. Adding an excerpt fixes things.